# jquery find and replace string inside a variable

Tags: jquery, replace

I've been searching for ages and can't seem to find an answer to what I would think is quite a simple question. I've used `.clone()` to make a copy of a `li` containing several form fields and then i'm inserting it at the beginning of the form. This works fine.

What I am trying to do is find and replace all instances of `ROWID` with variable `i`

```
<ul class="form">
<li class="hide">
    <ol class="form">
        <li><label for="cat_id_ROWID">Category:</label>
            <select id="cat_id_ROWID" name="cat_id[]">
                <option>...options...</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="value_ROWID">Value:</label>
            <input id="value_ROWID" name="value[]">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="description_ROWID">Description:</label>
            <textarea id="description_ROWID" name="description[]"></textarea>
        </li>
    </ol>
</li>
</ul>
```

Any my jquery is:

```
 var newitem = $('li.hide').eq(0).clone();
 newitem.removeClass('hide').addClass('row');
 $(newitem).insertBefore('ul.form li:first');
```

I'm trying to do something like `$(newitem).replace('ROWID',i);` but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `newitem` variable is a jQuery object, not a string, so a simple `.replace` won't work. You'll have to select the elements you want within `newitem` and change the attributes (which *are* strings) individually.

```
var $newitem = $('li.hide').eq(0).clone();
$('[for$="ROWID"]', $newitem).each(function () {
    $(this).attr('for', $(this).attr('for').replace('ROWID', i));
});
$('[id$="ROWID"]', $newitem).each(function () {
    $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id').replace('ROWID', i));
});
$newitem.removeClass('hide').addClass('row');
$newitem.insertBefore('ul.form li:first');
```

Answer (score 2):

newitem is the `li` and not the attribute.
Try someting like this:

```
newitem.html(newitem.html().replace("ROWID",i));
```

Comment: you also can only edit the attributes via attr() function :) its nearly the same way!

Comment: thanks for your reply, unfortunately this hasn't worked for me. @nachito 's solution has though. Is it possible to flatten the jQuery object so that it's just html/text rather than a series of objects? Is that what you're trying to do with `.html()`?

Comment: if you're using .html() you get everything in your container as html or if you use .text() as text. then you can use every string manipulation you want. then you can insert it again. Just look at http://api.jquery.com/html/ and http://api.jquery.com/text/